# Spring.Net + ASP: Page instantiated twice

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, spring.net

I've based my project on **Spring**'s *Northwind* example, but I must be doing something wrong.  I'm having Spring construct a DAO object and inject it into an ASP page, which it does, but I see that the same page gets constructed by **IIS**, without the benefit of **Spring**'s injection, and it's that latter page that gets run.

The page, **WorkFlowDetail.aspx**, inherits from a base class called **BasePage1**.  **BasePage1** has a public property for the DAO, giving us something like this:

**BasePage1.vb**:

```
Public Class BasePage1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private _wfdao As IWfDao
    Public Property wfDao As IWfDao
        Get
            Return _wfdao
        End Get
        Set(value As IWfDao)
            _wfdao = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

**WorkFlowDetail.aspx.vb**:

```
Public Class WorkFlowDetail
    Inherits BasePage1
End Class
```

**Web.xml**:

```
  <object name="BasePage1">
    <property name="wfDao" ref="wfDao" />
  </object>

  <object type="WorkFlowDetail.aspx" parent="BasePage1">
  </object>
```

**Web.config**:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="spring">
      <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebContextHandler, Spring.Web" />
      <section name="parsers" type="Spring.Context.Support.NamespaceParsersSectionHandler, Spring.Core" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <spring>
    <parsers>
      <parser type="Spring.Data.Config.DatabaseNamespaceParser, Spring.Data" />
      <parser type="Spring.Transaction.Config.TxNamespaceParser, Spring.Data" />
    </parsers>
    <context annotation-config="">
      <resource uri="~/Config/Aspects.xml" />
      <resource uri="~/Web.xml" />
    </context>
  </spring>

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false" />
      <add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="Spring.Web.Support.PageHandlerFactory, Spring.Web"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="Spring" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule, Spring.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="SpringPageHandler" verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="Spring.Web.Support.PageHandlerFactory, Spring.Web"/>
      <add name="SpringWebServiceHandler" verb="*" path="*.asmx" type="Spring.Web.Services.WebServiceHandlerFactory, Spring.Web" />
      <add name="SpringContextMonitor" verb="*" path="ContextMonitor.ashx" type="Spring.Web.Support.ContextMonitor, Spring.Web"/>
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" />
    </handlers>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="Spring" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule, Spring.Web" />
      <add name="OpenSessionInView" type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.Support.OpenSessionInViewModule, Spring.Data.NHibernate32" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="Spring.Data.NHibernate.Support.OpenSessionInViewModule.SessionFactoryObjectName" value="NHibernateSessionFactory" />
  </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

[Clearly I've left out a lot of stuff that I don't think is relevant.]

Setting a couple of strategic breakpoints I find that **WorkFlowDetail.aspx** gets constructed first by **Spring** and the DAO object is injected.  It shows up in the debugger's Watch list as a "(ASP.workflowdetail_aspx)" and the stack looks like this:

```
[External Code] 
Spring.Web.dll!Spring.Util.VirtualEnvironment.HttpRuntimeEnvironment.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(string virtualPath, System.Type requiredBaseType) Line 409 + 0x12 bytes  C#
Spring.Web.dll!Spring.Util.VirtualEnvironment.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(string virtualPath, System.Type requiredBaseType) Line 515 + 0x44 bytes C#
Spring.Web.dll!Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.WebObjectUtils.CreateHandler(string pageUrl) Line 156 + 0x20 bytes    C#
Spring.Web.dll!Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.WebObjectUtils.CreatePageInstance(string pageUrl) Line 105 + 0xc bytes    C#
Spring.Web.dll!Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.WebInstantiationStrategy.Instantiate(Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.RootObjectDefinition definition, string name, Spring.Objects.Factory.IObjectFactory factory) Line 76 + 0x50 bytes C#
Spring.Core.dll!Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.InstantiateObject(string objectName, Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.RootObjectDefinition definition) Line 1036 + 0x43 bytes C#
Spring.Core.dll!Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.CreateObjectInstance(string objectName, Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.RootObjectDefinition objectDefinition, object[] arguments) Line 1000 + 0x2a bytes    C#
Spring.Core.dll!Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.InstantiateObject(string name, Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.RootObjectDefinition definition, object[] arguments, bool allowEagerCaching, bool suppressConfigure) Line 904 + 0x21 bytes    C#
Spring.Core.dll!Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.GetObjectInternal(string name, System.Type requiredType, object[] arguments, bool suppressConfigure) Line 2037 + 0x3a bytes    C#
Spring.Core.dll!Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.CreateObject(string name, System.Type requiredType, object[] arguments) Line 1817 + 0x1e bytes C#
Spring.Core.dll!Spring.Context.Support.AbstractApplicationContext.CreateObject(string name, System.Type requiredType, object[] arguments) Line 1495 + 0x4d bytes    C#
Spring.Web.dll!Spring.Web.Support.PageHandlerFactory.CreateHandlerInstance(Spring.Context.IConfigurableApplicationContext appContext, System.Web.HttpContext context, string requestType, string rawUrl, string physicalPath) Line 108 + 0x85 bytes C#
Spring.Web.dll!Spring.Web.Support.AbstractHandlerFactory.GetHandler(System.Web.HttpContext context, string requestType, string url, string physicalPath) Line 208 + 0x43 bytes  C#
Spring.Web.dll!Spring.Web.Support.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler(System.Web.HttpContext context, string requestType, string url, string physicalPath) Line 77 + 0x23 bytes   C#
[External Code]
```

Then the constructor is called again.  This time the object shows up as "scheduleSite.WorkFlowDetail" in the debugger's Watch list and the stack just shows

```
[External Code]
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong with this configuration.  I've already tried leaving all mention of **BasePage1** out of **Web.xml**, with the same results.

**UPDATE**:

First-of-all, the page is being constructed more than just twice; I thought only twice because it was throwing an exception on the second time, but I find that if I get past there I hit the constructor 3-4 more times.

Second, I suspect that my problems stem from a misconfiguration of **Web.config**.  I notice that **Northwind** has only the <*system.web*> section, whereas my app (set up before I came onto the project) has both <*system.web*> and <*system.webServer*>.  **Northwind** is targeting **.NET 3.5** whereas we're targeting **4.0** and **IIS7.0** in **Integrated** mode.  I'm now looking into how to configure it, but would still appreciate help.

Comment: Is it working if you derive your base page from `Spring.Web.UI.Page` instead of `System.Web.UI.Page`?

Comment: Unfortunately, that made no difference.  Thanks for trying, though.